# Integrate phpdoc in gitlab for automatic doc generation

Tags: php, gitlab, phpdoc

I trying to integrate phpdoc in GitLab so that every time I am uploading my php code, docs will be generated automatically. I am a GitLab CI newbie.

it keeps failing because it cannot find phpdoc. I have tried to install it using composer but no luck.

my .gitlab-ci.yml  is the following

```
image: php:5.6

# Select what we should cache
cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
# Install git, the php image doesn't have installed
- apt-get update -yqq
- apt-get install git -yqq

# Install mysql driver
- docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Install all project dependencies
- php composer.phar install


services:
- mysql

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: hello_world_test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql

#Generate docs
generatedocs:
  script: "phpdoc -d . -t docs/api"
```

and my composer.json is

```
{
  "require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "1.*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor":"2.*"
  }
}
```

It fails with phpdoc not found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the path? From the [phpDoc site](https://phpdoc.org/) "_Once the installation is complete there will be a command phpdoc.php in the binary folder of your application (/vendor/bin by default)._"

Answer (score 1):

`vendor/bin/phpdoc` is probably the runtime command you'll need to use.